# Two different issues with dates and qplots

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, time-series

I am a student and have been given a project to study climate data from Giovanni (NASA). Our code is provided and we are left to 'find our way' and therefore other answers don't seem to relate to the style of code i've been given. Further to this i am a beginner in R so changing the code is very difficult.

Basically i'm trying to create a time-series plot from the following code:

```
## Function for loading Giovanni time series data
load_giovanni_time <- function(path){
file_data <- read.csv(path, 
                      skip=6,
                      col.names = c("Date",
                                    "Temperature",
                                    "NA",
                                    "Site",
                                    "Bleached"))
file_data$Date <- parse_date_time(file_data$Date, orders="ymdHMS")
return(file_data)
}

## Creat a list of files
file.list <- list.files("./Data/courseworktimeseries/")
file.list <- as.list(paste0("./Data/courseworktimeseries/", file.list))

# for(i in file.list){
#   load_giovanni_time(i)
# }

#Load all the files
all_data <- lapply(X=file.list,
                     FUN=load_giovanni_time)
all_data <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, all_data))


## Inspect the data with a plot
p <- qplot(data=all_data,
       x=Date,
       y=Temperature,
       colour=Site,
       linetype=Bleached,
       geom="line")
print(p)
```

Now the first problem is that when the data is merged into one dataset, it changes all the dates (the starting date range is 2002-2015 and it changes to 2002-2030), which obviously ruins the plot. I found that i can stop the dates changing by deleting this code:

```
file_data$Date <- parse_date_time(file_data$Date, orders="ymdHMS")
```

However, when this is deleted, i get the following error:

geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

Could anyone help me get round this without editing the code too much? I feel like it's a problem with the line of the code formatting the date incorrectly or something so i imagine it's only a small problem. I'm just very much a beginner and have to implement the code within 1-2 days.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who ever has this problem... I found the solution.

```
file_data$Date <- parse_date_time(file_data$Date, orders="ymdHMS")
```

This line of code reads in the date information from my CSV in that order. In excel my date was the other way round so if it said 30th December 2015 (30/12/2015), R would read it in as 2030-12-20, screwing up the data.

In Excel select all dates, CTRL+1 and then change format to match the date R is 'parsing'.

All done =)

Comment: Why not change `orders` to be in the order of date-time in the dataset so it works correctly?  Like `orders = "dmyHMS"`.

Comment: I can't remember exactly but when i tried this it wasn't plotting properly for some reason.